# Redirecting output of a program to a rotating file

Tags: linux, bash, redirect, logrotate

I am trying to redirect the output of a **continuously** running program to a file say `error_log`.

The command I am using looks like this, where `myprogram.sh` runs continuously generating data and writing to `/var/log/httpd/error_log`

- `myprogram.sh >> /var/log/httpd/error_log`

Now I am using `logrotate` to rotate this file per hour. I am using `create` command in `logrotate` so that it renames the original file and creates a new one.
The `logrotate` config looks like

```
/var/log/httpd/error_log {
# copytruncate
 create
 rotate 4
 dateext
 missingok
 ifempty
 .
 .
 .
}
```

But here redirection fails. What I want is `myprogram.sh` to write data to `error_log` file irrespective of it being rotated by logrotate, obviously to newly generated `error_log` file

Any idea how to make redirection work based on the **file name** and **not** the **descriptor** ?

OR

Any other way of doing it in bash ?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. When you do output redirection, it uses the filename, not a descriptor. Could you show your script?

Comment: Yes, can you please also show the entire  `logrotate` command as you have used it?

Comment: Why you don't use copytruncate, thus myprogram.sh might continue writing
              (appending) to the previous log file. You will not have the problem with create (it's like mv).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understood your problem, one solution (without modify `myprogram.sh`) could be:

```
$ myprogram.sh | while true; do head -10 >> /var/log/httpd/error_log; done
```

Explaining:

- `myprogram.sh` writes to stdout
- We redirect this output to `while` bash sentence through a pipe `|`.
- `while true` is an infinite loop that will never end, nor even when `myprogram.sh` ends which should break the pipe.
- In each loop `head` command is called to append the first 10 lines read from the pipe to the end of current `/var/log/httpd/error_log` file (that may be different from the last loop because of `logrotate`).

(You can change the number of lines being written in each loop)

And another way is:

```
$ myprogram.sh | while read line; do echo "$line" >> /var/log/httpd/error_log; done
```

- That's very similar to the first one, but this ends the loop when `myprogram.sh` ends or closes it's stdout.
- It works line by line instead in groups of lines.

Comment: Is there any significant slowdown with this method? heard while reads are very slow?

Comment: It'll depend on your needs. Suppose that `myprogram.sh` writes several MBs per second to the stdout, then neither of the alternatives I posted will be fast enough and the pipe will be blocked (the maximum pipe's capacity is approx ~64KB depending on the system), but if the program writes only a few lines per second (which a log normally does), then both alternatives should do the work and you probably won't feel any noticeable difference between them.